# bind variable and shell scripting with sqlplus

Tags: shell-script, variable, sqlplus

I wish to execute DMLs using bind variable with shell scripts.
For example, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

SH_NUM=10

sqlplus -S test_user/test_pass <<EOD
var a number;
a:=${SH_NUM}
insert into test_table values(a);
commit;
EOD
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, I can use this approch when using pl/sql but I wish to know if I can do it this method as well.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the assigment line, it should be changed to:

```
exec :a :=${SH_NUM};
```

Comment: So it's fixed now?

Comment: Yes, it solve the issue.